# variance negatif?

Tags: statistics

whether the variance of the parameters obtained from the inverse observed information matrix can be negative? I am looking for a variant of the parameters in a way to make "observed information matrix", after that I find the inverse of the observed information matrix, and I found the main diagonal is negative. is this possible?

whether the proof if the variance of the parameters obtained from the inverse observed information matrix is always positive?

Answer (score 1):

No: since by definition $Var(X) = {\mathbb E}[(X - {\mathbb E}X)^2]$, variance is always nonnegative.